# Microsoft-Excel: Trying to convert a square feet to acres easily for a large set of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set with 10,000+ items. I am trying to convert the square footage to acreage. Every item has a different square footage and I want to type in a function that will convert each 10,000 or so items to the specific acreage. E.g. item number 6 is 30056.4 square feet and I want the column beside it to populate 0.0047 acres and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

1 sq. feet is `1/43560 acres`.

So, when you have a data like this:

[image: sq foot]

Make a column for acres, and use this formula: `=ROUND(A2/43560, 4)`.
Drag down to fill other cells in the column:

[image: acres]

Here, `ROUND()` will round-off the values to the decimal places that you specify. Using this formula will round-off the values in acres to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know

```
1square feet = 0.00002296acres
```

Is the calculated result (30056.4 square feet = 0.0047 acres) incorrect?

If the result is correct, try this formula:

```
=A1*(0.0047/30056.4)
```

[image]

Or you should use this formula:

```
=A1*0.00002296
```

[image]